# Is there a way to query the run list from within a chef recipe?

Tags: chef

I want to have a condition to do something in a chef recipe only if there is no other recipe in the run list, and another that will be true only if a specific recipe is not in the run list. Is there a way to do this?

Also, what does the best practices say about this kind of logic? Should this be avoided from some reason?

Answer (score 0):

In general this kind of thing can be very fragile as if you are using `include_recipe`, things might be sensitive to order. But that said, you can do it:

```
if node['recipes'].include?('foo::bar')
  # Do something ...
end
```